# I need help applying an Api from sell.app

Tags: python, python-requests, sdk

I feel like I've done everything correctly but I'm still getting an client Error on 403, if anyone mind helping me this is the code:

```
import requests

url = "https://sell.app/api/v2/invoices/1/deliverables"

payload = ""
headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer {APIKEYHERE}"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Link : https://developer.sell.app/invoices-v2#the-invoice-model

I also tried this code as well:

```
import requests

url = "https://sell.app/api/v1/invoices/1"

payload = ""
headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer {ApiKeyHere}"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Link : https://developer.sell.app/invoices#retrieve-an-invoice

I'm trying to retrieve data from an order id, I tried filling the payload with the order id it still returns an error, I also tried using their Python Sdk but also got an error

> ```
> import sellapp
> api = sellapp.Api("ApiKey")
> orders = api.get_order("1321550")
>
> print(orders)
> ```

Error : {'message': 'No query results for model [App\Models\Invoice].'}
Link : https://github.com/qoft/sellapp

Error for the Requests Method :

> Just a
>
> moment...Enable
> JavaScript and cookies to
> continue(function(){window._cf_chl_opt={cvId:
> '2',cZone: "sell.app",cType: 'interactive',cNounce: '34623',cRay:
> '818e4c87dbd93fee',cHash: 'ee2c6c7965a5776',cUPMDTk:
> "/api/v2/invoices/1/deliverables?__cf_chl_tk=R5eSmvasmR8FzvlLP_s9lhneZgSyQ6CvWK4LSlpNN1Y-1697773850-0-gaNycGzNCmU",cFPWv:
> 'b',cTTimeMs: '1000',cMTimeMs: '0',cTplV: 5,cTplB: 'cf',cK:
> "visitor-time",fa:
> "/api/v2/invoices/1/deliverables?__cf_chl_f_tk=R5eSmvasmR8FzvlLP_s9lhneZgSyQ6CvWK4LSlpNN1Y-1697773850-0-gaNycGzNCmU",md:
> "6jmcr.E3PZeNYisrLv6dOXEqxBFcqXQ392WbnLDE2CY-1697773850-0-ASXcccp5Bv0xm-hZJAmMHkUsHtUnh2juK3lTgtwOA0vmMkqlIrawHvqGvEdLhi3-TUg97tKwJubu3NVE_HASetMdrYvO3s2GW0D1pZMaeWeuh8Vh8GaOm_7ujwVZE8EQ7KAkVhgdLmkEGCV4PXwywRyd4I5Ve7QFi3l6K-Fac0gRhWw9aGTOeHQmBXb09NNcCDcvHC0KIjKX7keVwAfQFjNSPrjuWDkfqeGJcJooG4K-Kq_HiVAZdJZEtYDLJlLd1L0OagjGigfSIAuMYMQSzoEn9tataz2HEU1cRPhl6Imp7aFNwpKo227T4XTun6veslKvtZi5y61bxWU8JhRKEK0HRuD5IT-CE8hDdKOTuArDkmmTPKEeYC__k5HVvL0_p0Lr5b9CnxJGv-6UUC4MLeDKeZYhaDIB6mRk4ydXpd8QneIauZD1M_zVvdAhbcs25Sg4u1L6tx4EA7g0IGRlXE9TBX4owMz62IAAJRJ2B7kO2rjcciyolMhrxOMGFuM8hfNESxkZ1KdjW1hDfGLUpe9TgTHRuBeRcX8UxbtikTRqQoJxtL87EMMDR1LacQpAYtqLjSbPb0fxb7kncxf2JgfI5swOWGhO1iv5yYZpYVTu5JusJh8-GCMQitIYLpn2Nc26m_HjBmtFt8KDJFjH4jumW4M3O4M0wn0XKTVOH9iugaxsFbk6PO2TUVBp878SJfxcjuw1XXDfumtsuN7XSMz62HvsxRSvJQgMe0D8ohH-dIX_0BgKAc_ZqHWOWzzRZooZbuBcu6NOKeHH8ZePT5Sl5vTmv7vFQT5tQRqXJ--5i11TJ-Fy5WJ9zCX_CwCiqhzo9jsE7GL8mpR-fj1SKZSFNJba7FgdQO-NWPZIydLupAuTa7fPcS_Y8IXoeQI9oNUhBzmLaQvhWq8_scag6Xq00fB3DG-xTbLHLDO94f4Z6zbRvjINCrL85o6rB7wq2EaHCet_PCLf-mAI1CLrzyEpzTlBZqnW1mwvE6rAhN2-8T6taH_VRCVoaG9QZKd2e3VHINjHNbZyUqq6J0mJdwTXwqhWSmPBUGQAlCQqcw2j0PlPg5FDkBpLEG-DpSN_tW5nRvc8CC5be3OkH_xFjyrvjny8ThrZTrEMf48URDM4ldCQ4t7HYnTiwoOE49IhEXf1xLYjo2S-4rXTkUZYrlOgn91UZOyOfAWfSvncQ-ugbTXo9Grf12KGhZwKE9s2vbvg_5ArteT-T74JUz7oNKTRTCSqW-mxutsg1lezV2xd7cDcY5j0VhM0j3N6zufzyDabkQCYsufA4o9VhPI-pXa4ej36Li_mUxu4ejJRYfZ_Yi43RQ1yDhNnnidGsMaI2bSsIsZzx6EEJ1tyOijmIJJks06TRj1Q--aHBmDSAyPpJ5-S_tIk3MTOahKZt4nZR_x_qnGVNxDZ5-*H__yRYyYMroLRyWUz8vYqIZ-3ZT7fL7kZKMCK7vxMqROUG1G1nokjwaA0q3_e18td7tMze32vRT9dbP5Bo1DzOAZtuIN4XCfdnaqaCi-NIw_xqsZ5hJK7ylAIxEW9nTQxuVIxGqBkt5dd7C1UPv1M_oawLzyr7jTKqd_GtSoIOg0kYekdxp5jHc2bCuJGlc2o0Jig3zQPYjXaZaFjxt11JxmNFK7DbPTC0VV9N8vyprfKzkS4En_gvGvm7ob9V0XlGycnYcX9jIcxeBVk1HxGEyK0kBSN_kAKjR9A9u_CZZXdIsdz4vBY_xS8qiedQva344FgLnxyiUVL4rREbfryLRMkT0n-h-3t2BtBWJPY8U2sKTnbbT5RK9ReKLCpcPPRcF63VGFuKr1194Jwxzv7IMHNpIwWs3vKgGym4r9N7QrzMn9rjzNszU54xQ8SHSjhMI0tmAckyAPMxi3L3ZmzaZYsuuuk4SJdKf2wPGWQ33sIU6ctFURy1wh67frxNdbZacDuD465FQkZ_SS2luOjYcFgkSBUMlB6btdzf2WPKblVCsNLO3EyYac9tDxlLGgKYYwfGTUmekfsg5b1TEdXWciGRifEHuioKtC7IiXO8e6d8jIAz*-y-LJLzpedD4JoUmfZzX7-u6EN9iGMtxaSHkxWcE74o0GwCtzbCuS-i9f0tkqMYGhjIh1xfUQ_k7DTT04V5cSVS9zK4dwJxget2MHFOcZvIl4momskgyz1CH6YRbss1bJ9DusaRAxM5QxD9OAcoRe4EpmjWRtFClYgh5p74T6Ij8BsAsQ82AD9Dd7F3cxkby555lw11tTJhP0scAjirEg-kcP2WhXHkC5xL3sQo380NBLHVDZSjwYeJLYHRZGsiVilSUwdJsBbec0DUOjmS0xLW1hOsPpJkHOyEJ0eSgcorZ5WGmGCEAaToGfIujV7LGERSlZnMyP3T1tgOCjG90wUM17zdytOHF3nCxrqw2E4tPpw3keH0bSlWMsjbClFzev0SH0HcEXWMBUbHE_P-3S4wY8mMNfK4wfebajUu1M6nwfkzhX-b-lSW_6u_h8embZXyXtEv-XgtlvXDKP7b65jPOeFBzzg25qEkt15_xv3Z8XqVJyQPb-_RnYU-L8OosxlSBVaXXmtxigr7iVBTdRjD1qWjikhjptWXQvzkndk",cRq:
> {ru:
> 'aHR0cHM6Ly9zZWxsLmFwcC9hcGkvdjIvaW52b2ljZXMvMS9kZWxpdmVyYWJsZXM=',ra:
> 'cHl0aG9uLXJlcXVlc3RzLzIuMjguMg==',rm: 'R0VU',d:
> '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',t:
> 'MTY5Nzc3Mzg1MC44NjAwMDA=',cT: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),m:
> '9vRMg5DdBGYOg4s56hAYeXm7kWqROkViI6C4U53gq6E=',i1:
> 'CEjNn3IqVfMAljb075EFpg==',i2: 'ZVsWJDps82AlA2pwCXTUIA==',zh:
> 'sqC8C0ww1n8rbBzyg5hcUjeIYp+4ByF8MMDQ3CPXBxM=',uh:
> 'neMFmDCz0LRc0/Wea+5x0IhJieHbzcQVSkMgFkgnrjc=',hh:
> '0XL1B86t53M5ny80vqU0T+QhdgJPSKKEd1t/G1Ao9MQ=',}};var cpo =
> document.createElement('script');cpo.src =
> '/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/b/orchestrate/chl_page/v1?ray=818e4c87dbd93fee';window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash
> = location.hash === '' && location.href.indexOf('#') !== -1 ? '#' : location.hash;window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery = location.search ===  ''
> && location.href.slice(0, location.href.length -
> window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash.length).indexOf('?') !== -1 ? '?' :
> location.search;if (window.history && window.history.replaceState)
> {var ogU = location.pathname + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery +
> window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash;history.replaceindow._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash);cpo.onload
> = function() {history.replaceState(null, null, ogU);}}document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);}());